# Smooth Paint Brush

Tags: objective-c, core-graphics, quartz-graphics, paint

I am developing  an iPad Application which allows the users to select the Air Brush , this is being achieved by drawing the image texture in the current context.

But when i draw the image i am getting this king of effect - [image]

where as to avoid this i tried using blendmodeLighten ,  which give me the right way as below
[image]

but using this i came across the another problem, where when i draw another color on the top of one color , due to blending i am not the getting the actual color.

Can any one help me on this  ?

Comment: Any one one this can help me please

Comment: Do i have any one to help me on this Please....

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what you want.

You can create another bitmap context using `CGBitmapContextCreate`, and draws the strokes on that context.

And using blend mode `kCGBlendModeColor`, you can combine with current context and bitmap context.

Hope it helps.